# Highlighting sections of text on a button press

Tags: javascript, html

This is my first time writing HTML/Javascript. I have a number of buttons and when pressed they change an image - all is OK.

I want to also make the description of what is happening in the image to be highlighted once the button has been pressed. It also needs to go back to not being highlighted when one of the other buttons is pressed.

I have played around with if statements etc but i cant seem to get it working.

This is what I have so far:

```
<button class="rbutton" onclick="R1Change()" style="position:absolute; Left:47.1%; Top: 70.7%; z-index: +1"></Button>

function R1Change() { 
    var img = document.getElementById("image"); 
    img.src="S1.png"; 
    return false; 
}
```

Any tips?

Comment: Hello and welcome, it would be good to show us your code, so that we can see what you have already.

Comment: please add your code.

Comment: So this is an example of the button

<button class="rbutton" onclick= "R1Change()"Style="position:absolute; Left:47.1%; Top: 70.7%; z-index: +1"></Button>                                                    

And this is the script for it:


function R1Change()
{
var img = document.getElementById("image");
img.src="S1.png";
return false;
}

Comment: @J.Butterworth just fyi, all functions do not need to return in Javascript, only those functions from which you want a value (e.g. `a = add(x, y)`)

Comment: @J.Butterworth please edit your original question instead of posting a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Here a simple example in vanilla JavaScript (no jQuery or other libraries).

The key part is changing the style property of your `target` element/description (I have also added few brief comments which tell you what the script does).

```
description.style.backgroundColor = 'orange'
```

```js
var button = document.getElementById('button'); // find button
var description = document.getElementById('figcaption'); // find description
var changeDescription = function() {
  // change color for the description
  description.style.backgroundColor = 'orange';
};
button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  // detect click on button
  changeDescription();
});
```

```html
<button id="button">Clcik me please</Button>

<figure>
  <img src="http://pipsum.com/435x310.jpg" alt="The Pulpit Rock" width="304" height="228">
  <figcaption id="figcaption">Fig1. - Your description here.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Alternatively you could have also used [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

```
description.classList.add("yourClass");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer- however when i run the code it doesnt seem to work. When i check in the console thedescription.style.backgroundColor = 'orange' is underlined in red. Do you know why this is?

Comment: @J.Butterworth Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is just change the background-color of the text description to the color you want the highlight to be. Should be something like (basing off your comment with the code):

```
<button class="rbutton" onclick= "R1Change()"Style="position:absolute; Left:47.1%; Top: 70.7%; z-index: +1"></Button>
```

-

```
function R1Change() { 
 var img = document.getElementById("image");
 var description = document.getElementById("description");
 description.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
 img.src="S1.png"; 
 return false; 
}
```